# Use Wolfram Cloud to Create Site Visitor Database

Tags: geography, apifunction

**Question:** Is there a way to use Wolfram Cloud to create a web API function that, when pinged, does the following:

1. Gets the geographical location of the user (as an Wolfram entity, like `California, USA` or `Germany` instead of raw coordinates) and adds to a tally of site visitors by location (probably as a Wolfram Association)?  Something roughly of form `<| "California, USA" -> 2, "Germany" -> 1, ... |>`. It doesn't have to be like this, but this just seems natural at first glance.
2. Returns text to the user who curls it?

**Example.** So for example of a user does something like

```
curl www.wolframcloud.com/...
```

the response in their console should be

```
Welcome to my webpage!
```

and, internally, some Wolfram Association with the geographical data should be updated so that I can check my account to see how many people visited us/where it came from.

**Attempt.** The following functions seem useful: `APIFunction`, `GeoLocation` (problem: returns coordinates and not entity locations).

Comment: You can use `HTTPRequestData` inside your API code to get the metadata of the request. Also `$GeoLocationCountry` will give you country of the user.